# Symfony 3, разный редирект после авторизации для разных ролей

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3

У меня есть две роли

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Мне нужно чтобы для пользователейпосле после авторизации с ролью ADMIN был редирект в /admin
А для пользователей с ролью USER был редирект на /user
Сейчас в файле security у меня так:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path:            /admin

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

Как мне нужно модифицировать security или ещё что-то добавить, чтобы решить задачу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В разделе `firewalls` вы должны иметь 2 подраздела. Один для обычных клиентов а второй для менеджеров.
 И вы можете дать группу страниц которые должны быть доступны для конкретной группе клинентов с помощью `pattern`. Например `pattern: /admin(.*)`

В итоге у вас должно получиться  такой `config`

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path:            /user 

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
    admin:
        pattern: /admin(.*)
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path:            /admin

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! То что нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно использовать один firewall (например, чтобы авторизованный админ на фронте тоже был авторизован), то можно использовать `success_handler` в firewall [SecurityBundle Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)

security.yml

```
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path: /login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            failure_handler: user.authentication.failure_handler
            success_handler: user.authentication.success_handler
```

services.yml

```
services:
    user.authentication.success_handler:
        class: UserBundle\Security\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
        arguments: ["@router"]
```

AuthenticationSuccessHandler.php

```
class AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    /** @var I18nRouter */
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(I18nRouter $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $token->getUser();

        // Проверяем роль пользователя, генерим url через router, возвращаем ответ с редиректом

        return $response;
    }

}
```